# How to Capture Only Subimage from Rasperry Pi Camera?

Tags: camera, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and Raspberry Pi. I want to increase the frame rate on the camera (preferably > 300 fps), but I don't need the full image. Instead of sending back the full azimuth and elevation that the camera supports, is there a way to capture a box bounded by, say, (300, 300) and (600, 600)?

I have not started writing code yet so this approach need not be compatible with any existing code.

Comment: that kind of info should be in the camera module datasheet

Comment: @jsotola I think you mean hardware, but is that correct? If so, is that a parameter that OpenCV and the like allow you to modify?